# Time Stamp to Date conversion to reverse

Tags: datetime, unix-timestamp

i am stuck while doing timestamp conversion.When i convert timestamp to date, I am getting the correct date and time. But the reverse is wrong. I am not able to convert date and time to timestamp properly. My timestamp value is 1369315110870 and am getting the date as 5/23/2013 1:18:30 PM. But in reverse calculation am getting the timestamp value as 1369315110000 . Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Please post the code snippet how you convert timestamp to date and date to timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not dealing with a unix timestamp. [Unix timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) are expressed in seconds since the epoch, while the values you're showing are milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 01 1970).

Hence also the difference between the two values: it's the 870 milliseconds that were present in the original timestamp value, but were not represented in the date string. Converting the date string back to a timestamp then gives you a timestamp value with 0 milliseconds.